# ViewPager that listens to clicks

Tags: android, xamarin, android-viewpager

I need a `ViewPager` that enables to user to swipe images. But on a click on the images, a n**ew activity has to start with another**, bigger viewpager that contains the same images.

How can i implement a click listener while still keeping the swipe on the `viewpager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty straight-forward, and has nothing to do with your ViewPager. Just add onClickListener to your ImageView:

```
ImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // start new activity here
        }
    }
});
```

or add the onClick in XML:

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:onClick="startTheOtherActivity" />
```